# Numerical instability of gradient descent in C

Tags: c, precision, numerical-methods, gradient-descent

I wrote a simple gradient descent algorithm with the steepest descent method.

For steepes descent i mean that the step size is optimized to be the one that minimizes f(x - lambda*grad(f)) with lambda the step size with the result that each direction is orthogonal to the preceding.

The problem is that the program seems very unstable: it works (kinda) well only with quadratic functions but with even quartic functions like x^4 + y^4 + z^4 is unstable no matter the precision used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double l2_norm(double *x1, double *x2, int m);
void get_grad(double (*f)(double *x, int m), double *x, double *grad, int m);
void copy(double *a, double *b, int m);
void add(double *a, double *b, double lambda, int m);
double dFdLambda(double (*f)(double *x, int m), double *x, double *u, int m);
void descent(double (*f)(double *x, int m), double *x, double *u, int m);

void print_vec(double *x, int m){
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);
    }
    return;
}

double f_temp(double *x, int m){

    double f=0.;

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        f += (x[i]-1)*(x[i]-1);
    }
    return f;
}

int main(){

    double x[] = {2., 2., 2.};
    double *grad;
    double *x_old;
    int m = 3;
    double e = 1.E-6;

    grad = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    x_old = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    
    while(l2_norm(x, x_old, m) > e){
        copy(x, x_old, m);
        get_grad(f_temp, x, grad, m);
        descent(f_temp, x, grad, m);
        print_vec(x, m);
    }

    printf("\n");
    print_vec(x, m);
    

    return 0;
}


double l2_norm(double *x1, double *x2, int m){

    double norm = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        norm += pow(x1[i]-x2[i], 2);
    }

    norm = sqrt(norm);

    return norm;
}


void get_grad(double (*f)(double *x, int m), double *x, double *grad, int m){
    /*
    numerical gradient with simmetric method

    the actual gradient computed is -grad in order to be used in 
    gradient descent
    */
    double e = 1.E-6; // numerical precision
    double *x_forward;
    double *x_backward;
    x_forward = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    x_backward = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    
    for(int i=0;i<m; i++){
        x_forward[i] = x[i] + e;
        x_backward[i] = x[i] - e;    
        grad[i] = -(f(x_forward, m) - f(x_backward, m))/(2*e);
        x_forward[i] -= e;
        x_backward[i] += e;
    }
    free(x_forward);
    free(x_backward);
    return;
}


double dFdLambda(double (*f)(double *x, int m), double *x, double *u, int m){
    /*
    compute the total derivative dF/dLambda in the point x along
    the direction u
    */
    double e = 1.E-5;
    double *x_forward;
    double *x_backward;
    double der;

    x_forward = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    x_backward = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    copy(x, x_forward, m);
    copy(x, x_backward, m);
    add(x_forward, u, e, m);
    add(x_backward, u, -e, m);

    der = (f(x_forward, m) - f(x_backward, m))/(2*e);

    free(x_forward);
    free(x_backward);

    return der;
}


void copy(double *a, double *b, int m){
    //copies a into b
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    return;
}


void add(double *a, double *b, double lambda, int m){
    /*
    adds lambda*b to a
    */
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        a[i] += lambda*b[i];
    }
    return;
}


void descent(double (*f)(double *x, int m), double *x, double *u, int m){
    /*
    actual gradient descent starting from x going in direction u
    */
    double e = 1.E-5;
    double derA, derB, derC;
    double *x_start;
    double lambda, lambda_min, lambda_max;

    lambda = e;

    x_start = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
    copy(x, x_start, m);
    derA = dFdLambda(f, x, u, m);
    derC = derA;

    /*
    this while loop finds the interval in which the total derivatives df/dl
    changes sign i.e. the interval in which the solution of df/dl = 0
    will be searched with bisection method
    */
    while((derA*derC) >= 0.){
        copy(x_start, x, m);
        add(x, u, lambda, m);
        derC = dFdLambda(f, x, u, m);
        lambda *= 2.;
    }

    /*
    because lambda >= 0 the leftmost point of the interval is 0, the rightmost 
    the point found before after which the total derivatives changes sign
    */
    lambda_min = 0;
    lambda_max = lambda;
    lambda = 0.5*(lambda_min + lambda_max);

    while((fabs(lambda_max - lambda_min)) > e){
        copy(x_start, x, m);
        add(x, u, lambda_min, m);
        derA = dFdLambda(f, x, u, m);

        copy(x_start, x, m);
        add(x, u, lambda, m);
        derB = dFdLambda(f, x, u, m);

        if((derA*derB) > 0.){
            lambda_min = lambda;
        } 
        else if((derA*derB) < 0.){
            lambda_max = lambda;
        }
        else{
            lambda_min = lambda_max = lambda;
        }

        lambda = 0.5*(lambda_min + lambda_max);
    }

    copy(x_start, x, m);
    // the modified vector x will cointain the coordinates of the minumum
    add(x, u, lambda, m); 
    free(x_start);

    return;
}
```

with `f += (x[i]-1)*(x[i]-1)` the output is correct

```
1.000005
1.000005
1.000005
-1.499995
-1.499995
1.000005
1.000012
1.000012
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000

1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
```

but using `(x[i]-1)*(x[i]-1)*(x[i]-1)*(x[i]-1)` or even the pow() function with power 2 the results are similar to

```
1.000010
1.000010
1.000010
-1.499990
-1.499990
1.000010
1.000292
1.000292
1.000010
1.000292
1.000000
1.000010
1.000292
-1032674302637538115769421495899732814941072310657452010951926707678661836800.000000
-171980112174886070524247400874370796081962558827236065865505533642887865040896.000000
inf
inf
nan

inf
inf
nan
```

Lowering the numerical precision inside the functions (the `double e` variables) seems to work only for simple quadratic functions (without using the pow() function), otherwise i get null or inf numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some issues with using allocated objects while their values are indeterminate.  The first one is in `main`:

> ```
>     x_old = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
>     
>     while(l2_norm(x, x_old, m) > e){
> ```

Note that you are using the data to which `x_old` points without ever having assigned any values to it.  Since you always want to do at least one iteration, it would make sense to restructure the `while` loop as a `do ... while`.

But you have some more in `get_grad()` that are probably a lot more impactful:

> ```
>     x_forward = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
>     x_backward = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
>     
>     for(int i=0;i<m; i++){
>         x_forward[i] = x[i] + e;
>         x_backward[i] = x[i] - e;    
>         grad[i] = -(f(x_forward, m) - f(x_backward, m))/(2*e);
>         x_forward[i] -= e;
>         x_backward[i] += e;
>     }
> ```

Note that you start using the data pointed-to by `x_forward` and `x_backward` right after allocation, when those values are undefined.  You *eventually* assign values to all the allocated elements, but you *initially* assign just element 0 of each.  Presumably, you want to copy the data from `x` into the spaces to which these point prior to starting the loop.  As presently written, without such copying, the resulting behavior is undefined.  **There is absolutely no reason to expect that the resulting data stored in `*grad` will be an estimate of the gradient at `x`.**

Even if you could rely on `malloc()` initializing the allocated space to all-zero (which it does not do, but `calloc()` does), the program would be wrong.  In particular, the `get_grad()` function would, in general, compute each component of the supposed gradient at a different point.

I was able to reproduce your program's erroneous output fairly closely.  The computation took a similar path, diverging to NaN after not too many iterations.

After fixing those two issues, the program produces this output instead:

```
1.000005
1.000005
1.000005
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000

1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
```

#### Update

The program also has an implementation error in function `dFdLambda()`.  It computes the derivative of *f* in the chosen direction as

> ```
>     der = (f(x_forward, m) - f(x_backward, m))/(2*e);
> ```

, but the divisor in that formula is incorrect, grossly so in some cases.  It should be the distance (L2 norm) between `x_forward` and `x_backward`.  When I make that correction, the resulting program converges in the quartic case, too.<sup>*</sup>

---

I imagine that you can probably still find input functions where the program misbehaves.  In particular, you may have trouble with functions that have even steeper gradients in the vicinity of the local minimum, and with those that oscillate very rapidly.  You may also have trouble with functions that are distinctly anisotropic in the various dimensions of the domain, and with functions that have local minimums with very large values.

Addressing the issue that [@chux describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76447870/2402272) would help with some of that.  A more adaptive approach to estimating the gradient and derivative might help with some others.

And the descent computation itself could be protected against divergence.  For example, it could verify that the value of *f* in fact does decrease, and / or the change in *x* per descent step could be damped or capped in various ways.

Also, I understand *mathematically* why `descent()` estimates derivatives of the function and uses them to search for a minimum along the chosen direction, by *computationally*, you would probably be better off searching for a minimum directly, using the values of the function instead of estimates of its derivative.  That would certainly reduce the likelihood of divergences such as you observed, and its convergence properties in general are likely to be as good or better.

Ultimately, however, numerical programs are constrained by the numeric representations they use, which inevitably have limited range and precision (though you can choose the specific limits more or less arbitrarily if you want to do).  This is a fundamental constraint of numerical programming.

---

<sup>*</sup>Though I'm not actually sure why it makes a difference, because the program seems to depend only on the sign of the derivative, not its magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i fixed the loop in the main() using a do...while loop and implemented copy(x, x_forward, m) and copy(x, x_backward, m) before the for loop in the get_grad() function (modifying the increments as x_forward[i] += e, x_backward[i] -= e before the computation of the gradient and x_forward[i] -= e, x_backward[i] += e after but with a quartic function like f += pow((x[i]-1), 4) the program is still unstable

Comment: @NiccolòTiezzi, I have identified another flaw in your program, and updated this answer to discuss it.  I also added some broader commentary about the program's general approach.

Comment: thank you very much, changing the denominator of the directional derivative indeed fixed the program for quartic functions. I don' t expect it to be actually usable for complicated function since i wrote it as a naive implementation for fun (just for convex and smooth functions) but your advices will be very useful for further study in scientifi programming

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76447138/2410359) good answer:

**Consider an alternate "closeness" test**

> is unstable no matter the precision used

Code currently compares values in a linear sense, yet floating point values are distributed about logarithmically - that is why they are call *floating* point and not *fixed* point.  They deserve a test that uses a test that changes per the magnitude of the arguments.  Otherwise all large number pairs are never "about equal" unless exactly equal and all small pairs are always equal.

```
double e = 1.E-5;
...
// while((fabs(lambda_max - lambda_min)) > e){
while(!about_equal(lambda_max, lambda_min, e)) {
```

Candidate `about_equal()` below is *illustrative* and not optimized.  How to best compare depends on details of OP's goals.

```
bool about_equal(double a, double b, double relative_error) {
  double diff = fabs(a - b);
  double magnitude = fmax(fabs(a), fabs(b));
  return diff <= magnitude * relative_error;
}
```